# Logging in Polars

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

I don't see any sort of logging implemented in Pola-rs.

I am curious to know what desgin decisions/ philosophy went behind choosing not to implement any loggings in pola-rs and how is the library debugged, if anyone is willing to throw some light at it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what type of logging capabilities you have in mind, but you can check out the inspect instruction.

Here are the links for the Polars API reference:

inspect for expressions:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.inspect.html#polars.Expr.inspect

inspect for lazyframes:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.inspect.html#polars.LazyFrame.inspect

Comment: These are more like debugger evaluators. I was thinking of loggers, for example, log4j.

Comment: One thing I would have liked to do is log the number of records after several filtering steps, but I couldn't without collecting the frames first (which clearly a bad option).